# How to fix Class 'Illuminate\Notifications\Notification' not found?

Tags: php, database, laravel

Every time I try to run my Test.php file, which is meant to send a notification, I am getting the error message: 
`Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Notifications\Notification' not found in /Users/Macbook/app/app/Http/Controllers/Test.php on line 12`.

Here is my Test.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

// use app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use App\User;

class Test extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

   /**
   * Create a new notification instance.
   *
   * @return void
   */

public $test;

public function __construct($test)
{
    $this->test = $test;
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['database'];
}

/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    /** 
    $url = url('/test/'.$this->test->id);

    return (new MailMessage)
                ->greeting('Hello!')
                ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                ->action('Notification Action', $url)
                ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    */
}

/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function toDatabase($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'data' => 'You have a new notification.',
        'from' => $this->message->name,
        'name'=> $this->message->email,
        'subject' => $this->message->subject,
        'body' => $this->message->body
    ];
}
}
```

I am trying to send notifications using the Database method. Could anyone help me out? It's just odd because I am sure that Illuminate\Notifications\Notification exists.

Answer (score 1):

> Notifications may be sent in two ways: using the notify method of the Notifiable trait or using the Notification facade.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications#sending-notifications

**Option 1**

You can use `notify()` method:

```
$user->notify(new AgendamentoPendente(1));
```

Also, make sure User class uses Notifiable trait:

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
```

**Option 2**

Using facade with full namespace:

```
\Notification::send($user, new AgendamentoPendente(1));
```

Comment: Where should I put this code? Inside Test.php? I still don't think that will fix the problem of a missing Class.

Comment: Hi. Would just like to ask: if using Option 1, where should that first line of code be put? And the same question applies for Option 2. It's obviously not just a command line - its PHP code. Where should I put it? What file and where? Thanks